# Redirect from React ASP.NET application to SSO login page blocked by CORS Policy

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, single-sign-on, fetch-api, saml

My application is set up as of follows:
Frontend is React (SPA),
Backend is ASP.NET Core 6, and
User will be authenticated via SSO using SAML2 protocol (the SAML code is implemented on the ASP.NET side, not React)

When the React page is loaded, it will send a POST request via fetch API to the ASP.NET server which then will trigger to load the SSO page (I'm actually confused by this as I'm unsure how this would work with React since React handles all the routing piece here). However, I keep getting an error that is saying:
"Access to fetch at 'https://sso.example.com/saml/idp/profile/redirectorpost/sso?SAMLRequest=xxxx&RelayState=ReturnUrl%3D%252Fexample%252Fexampleapp%252FGetLoggedInUser' (redirected from 'https://forms.test.com/test/testapp/GetLoggedInUser') from origin 'https://forms.test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request."

I attempted to fix this by changing the attributes in the fetch headers by all resulted in the same CORS error.

Here's my fetch api code on the frontend:

```
    fetch("testapp/GetLoggedInUser", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        },
        body: data
    }).then((response) => {
        const contentType = response.headers.get("content-type");
        if (contentType && contentType.indexOf("application/json") !== -1) {
            return response.json().then((data) => {
                return data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
        else {
            return response.text().then((data) => {
                return data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            })
        }
        
    });
```

My backend (ASP.NET Core 6)

```
//[Authorize] is an attribute from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute

        [Authorize]
        [HttpPost("GetLoggedInUser")]
        public string GetLoggedInUserData()
        {
            this.CheckSession();
            Person Person = new ActiveUser(this.ID, GlobalVariables.ProcessCode);
            dynamic P = Person.GetSimple();
            
            User User = new User(this.WhitworthID);
            P.LastAccess = DateTime.Now;
            User.SetLastAccess();
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(P);
        }
```

Can anyone advise me on how to get past the CORS error when redirecting from React to the SSO page?

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to check if the response is redirected,if so redirect the browser to the new url.

```
   fetch(url, { method: 'POST', redirect: 'manual'})
    .then(response => {
        // HTTP 301 response
        // HOW CAN I FOLLOW THE HTTP REDIRECT RESPONSE?
        if (response.redirected) {
            window.location.href = response.url;
        }
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.info(err + " url: " + url);
    });
```

Comment: I tried that but it still doesn't redirect to the SSO login page. I looked at the network on my developer console and saw that fetch has a status of "cancelled". Then, I found out that the if statement for response.redirected was never hit. I removed that statement and tried to assign window.location.href with the response.headers.get("Location") as it contains the destination url but still not successful. I also tried with exposing my response headers. The response.headers.get("Location") keep returning null even though I'm seeing a response for headers location in developer console.